# OpenCL kernel function yields different results when running on different devices (CPU vs GPU)

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

I'm trying to make a sense out of a strange behavior happening in my OpenCL kernel function. I'm basically trying to convert a string that contains hexadecimals, into a string that contains its decimal representation but, for reasons I cannot fathom, running the same kernel using GPU and CPU yield different results.

The kernel looks like the following:

```
 // yes, there's no result defined for the moment
__kernel void testKernel(__global uint message_length, __global char *message) {

  size_t converted_message_length = message_length / 2;
  char converted_message[converted_message_length];

  // (1) hex to decimal conversion 
  for (size_t idx = 0, j = 0; idx < converted_message_length; idx++, j++) {
    converted_message[idx] = (message[j] & '@' ? message[j] + 9 : message[j]) << 4;
    j++;
    converted_message[idx] |= (message[j] & '@' ? message[j] + 9 : message[j]) & 0xF;
    printf("converted '%c%c' into '%i'\n", message[j - 1], message[j], converted_message[idx]);
  }

  // (2) this should be redundant, since I already print the content...
  // but actually behaves differently with different device (CPU/GPU)
  for (size_t idx = 0, j = 0; idx < converted_message_length; idx++, j++) {
    printf("converted_message[%i]: '%i'\n", idx, converted_message[idx]);
  }
```

Now, if I pass as arguments of `testKernel` function the lenght `4`, and input string containing hexadecimal value `3e2b`, I would expect them to be converted into decimals `62` and `43` ([see this table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) for hex -> decimal conversion).

And, If I run the kernel using my CPU (Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H), indeed I can see the following conversion happening:

```
converted '3e' into '62'
converted '2b' into '43'
converted_message[0]: '62'
converted_message[1]: '43'
```

However, if I run this very same kernel using my GPU (AMD Radeon Pro 5500M), I see the following results:

```
converted '3e' into '62'
converted '2b' into '43'
converted_message[0]: '0'  <-- why it is 0 ???
converted_message[1]: '0'  <-- why it is 0 ???
```

It seems like `converted_message` is successfully written inside loop `(1)`, but then its values get lost when I enter inside `(2)` loop. How's that even possible? Is it the OpenCL performing some weird optimization under the hood, that manifest itself only when running in the GPU ?

Comment: How the kernel is scheduled?

Comment: I've had such issues once on the same device but with a different driver, although with floating-point where the compiler can change the order of operations so round-off errors may be different. Different outcomes shouldn't be possible with integer operations though. I suspect that on one device memory is not properly allocated/initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char converted_message[converted_message_length];
```

This is a variable length array which is [not supported in standard OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_C.html#_footnotedef_22). It might work on some OpenCL implementations as an extension, but is not portable.

Specify a fixed size for the array or allocate a buffer on the host.

Comment: well spotted, thanks a lot for pointing to the reference!